# `rescue in transmit': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified)

Tags: ruby, rest, ssl

Hi i have this error where `RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified`. I try to fixed this this with the instruction [here](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html) but still not working. what i notice is most the error here is related to sslv3 mine is different `state=error: certificate verify failed (RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified)`

Comment: Did you have any progress with that?

Comment: Finally I found the solution to my certificate issues: running `rvm osx-ssl-certs update all` solved it for me immediately. Found it here: https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/288